# homebrew llvm build cannot find iOS simulator library containing _wordexp symbol

Tags: xcode, macos, linker, cmake, llvm

I'm working on [touching up](https://gist.github.com/aw1621107/dccde531d91349d3eaee) homebrew's (OS X package manager) [llvm formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/llvm.rb). Unfortunately, something about the parts I added broke the build in a way I just cannot figure out.

tl;dr `ld` asks for a library containing a `_wordexp` symbol for iOS simulator, and I have absolutely no clue where it is, if it exists

Compilation consistently fails for me when the compiler is attempting to link the [address sanitizer](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html) dylib for iOS Simulator.

Reproduction steps (OS X only as far as I know, don't have *nix systems handy):

- install homebrew if it isn't already installed
- replace homebrew's llvm formula with the WIP one above
- Run `brew install llvm --with-clang --with-lldb --verbose --debug`
- wait for the build to fail and ask you what to do
- Drop into a debug shell
- cd to `projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan/CMakeFiles/clang_rt.asan_iossim_dynamic.dir`
- add the following line to `link.txt`

  ```
  -Wl,-syslibroot /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk
  ```
- go back up to `asan`
- Run `make`

At this point on my machine, something like this pops up:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_wordexp", referenced from:
      _wrap_wordexp in asan_interceptors.cc.o
      substitution_wordexp in asan_interceptors.cc.o
     (maybe you meant: _wrap_wordexp)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I thought that it was just a matter of adding another folder to the linker search path. Turns out it isn't that simple:

- `wordexp.h` is in `<path-to-iPhoneSimulator.sdk>/usr/include`, but running

  ```
  find . -type f -name "*.dylib" -print0 | xargs -0 nm | grep -n "T _wordexp" -B <large number> | less
  ```

  in Xcode-beta.app showed that the only .dylibs in Xcode that exported a `_wordexp` symbol were in the `WatchSimulator.platform` folder
- Running the same command in `/usr` showed that 3 libraries in `/usr/lib/system` exported `_wordexp` (`libsystem_asl`, `libsystem_c`, and `libsystem_blocks`), but the linker doesn't seem to care when I add `/usr/lib/system` to the search path even when the code is the x86_64 code it wants, and the corresponding dylibs I found for other platforms didn't contain `_wordexp`
- Googling about about this particular symbol missing turned up mostly stuff about Apple implementing `wordexp()` with Perl
- I think I remember seeing something in the llvm-dev mailing list archives about *BSD/OSX not implementing `wordexp`, but the header file is definitely there, `wordexp()` shows up in the manpages, and the functions declared in the header file seem to work just fine when compiling for OSX
- The symbol is not in the libc++(abi) dylibs compiled earlier in the build
- Every other part of the build compiles just fine except for the `asan` folder and its parents

---

What am I missing? Given that this error does not seem to be particularly common, there could be a chance it's my machine, but I'm hoping the chances are pretty low, because I wiped and reinstalled my computer this weekend.

(OS X 10.11, Xcode/CLT 7.1, mid-2012 Retina pro)

If more info is needed I'll be happy to provide it.

Edit 1: Simplified `link.txt` fix. Turns out setting sysroot for `clang++` doesn't do so for `ld`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the error was a result of the way homebrew processed compiler flags. That and a few other problems have been fixed since, so this probably isn't too useful any more.

---

For those curious about how exactly this broke, homebrew tries to change compiler flags to suppress warnings and create a more consistent building experience. One of these changes was to remove any `-isysroot` or `-system` flags, because that was added by homebrew itself at a later stage. Unfortunately, homebrew assumed that only the OS X SDK would be used, so when the build expected to build something with the iPhone simulator SDK it was pointed to the OS X SDK.