# Why might make produce a different object file than the same command copy-pasted and entered manually?

Tags: build, cmake, makefile, llvm

Sort of related to my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32595742/3580294), since this is also about building llvm.

When trying to get around a build failure in llvm, I noticed the following:

Output in terminal when building a single object file through `make`:

```
rp% make asan_posix.o
cd /tmp/llvm20150917-93899-y384cu && /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan/CMakeFiles/RTAsan_dynamic.iossim.dir/build.make projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan/CMakeFiles/RTAsan_dynamic.iossim.dir/asan_posix.cc.o
Building CXX object projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan/CMakeFiles/RTAsan_dynamic.iossim.dir/asan_posix.cc.o
cd /tmp/llvm20150917-93899-y384cu/projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan && /usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/clang++   -DASAN_DYNAMIC=1 -DASAN_HAS_EXCEPTIONS=1 -D_DEBUG -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -I/tmp/llvm20150917-93899-y384cu/projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan -I/tmp/llvm20150917-93899-1jg6jdx/projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan -I/tmp/llvm20150917-93899-y384cu/include -I/tmp/llvm20150917-93899-1jg6jdx/include -I/tmp/llvm20150917-93899-1jg6jdx/projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan/..  -fPIC -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wall -W -Wno-unused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wmissing-field-initializers -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wcovered-switch-default -Wnon-virtual-dtor -std=c++11 -Wall -std=c++11 -arch i386 -arch x86_64   -UNDEBUG   -fPIC -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wall -W -Wno-unused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wmissing-field-initializers -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wcovered-switch-default -Wnon-virtual-dtor -std=c++11 -Wall -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.1.sdk -fPIC -fno-builtin -fno-exceptions -fomit-frame-pointer -funwind-tables -fno-stack-protector -fvisibility=hidden -fno-function-sections -fno-lto -O3 -gline-tables-only -Wno-gnu -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-c99-extensions -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -fno-rtti -ftls-model=initial-exec -o CMakeFiles/RTAsan_dynamic.iossim.dir/asan_posix.cc.o -c /tmp/llvm20150917-93899-1jg6jdx/projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan/asan_posix.cc
cd /tmp/llvm20150917-93899-y384cu && /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan/CMakeFiles/RTAsan_dynamic.osx.dir/build.make projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan/CMakeFiles/RTAsan_dynamic.osx.dir/asan_posix.cc.o
Building CXX object projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan/CMakeFiles/RTAsan_dynamic.osx.dir/asan_posix.cc.o
cd /tmp/llvm20150917-93899-y384cu/projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan && /usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/clang++   -DASAN_DYNAMIC=1 -DASAN_HAS_EXCEPTIONS=1 -D_DEBUG -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -I/tmp/llvm20150917-93899-y384cu/projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan -I/tmp/llvm20150917-93899-1jg6jdx/projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan -I/tmp/llvm20150917-93899-y384cu/include -I/tmp/llvm20150917-93899-1jg6jdx/include -I/tmp/llvm20150917-93899-1jg6jdx/projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan/..  -fPIC -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wall -W -Wno-unused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wmissing-field-initializers -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wcovered-switch-default -Wnon-virtual-dtor -std=c++11 -Wall -std=c++11 -arch i386 -arch x86_64   -UNDEBUG   -fPIC -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wall -W -Wno-unused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wmissing-field-initializers -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wcovered-switch-default -Wnon-virtual-dtor -std=c++11 -Wall -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -fPIC -fno-builtin -fno-exceptions -fomit-frame-pointer -funwind-tables -fno-stack-protector -fvisibility=hidden -fno-function-sections -fno-lto -O3 -gline-tables-only -Wno-gnu -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-c99-extensions -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -fno-rtti -ftls-model=initial-exec -o CMakeFiles/RTAsan_dynamic.osx.dir/asan_posix.cc.o -c /tmp/llvm20150917-93899-1jg6jdx/projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan/asan_posix.cc


rp% file CMakeFiles/RTAsan_dynamic.iossim.dir/asan_posix.cc.o
CMakeFiles/RTAsan_dynamic.iossim.dir/asan_posix.cc.o: Mach-O 64-bit object x86_64
rp% file CMakeFiles/RTAsan_dynamic.osx.dir/asan_posix.cc.o
CMakeFiles/RTAsan_dynamic.osx.dir/asan_posix.cc.o: Mach-O 64-bit object x86_64
```

Output when the same commands are entered manually:

```
rp% cd /tmp/llvm20150917-93899-y384cu/projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan && /usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/clang++   -DASAN_DYNAMIC=1 -DASAN_HAS_EXCEPTIONS=1 -D_DEBUG -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -I/tmp/llvm20150917-93899-y384cu/projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan -I/tmp/llvm20150917-93899-1jg6jdx/projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan -I/tmp/llvm20150917-93899-y384cu/include -I/tmp/llvm20150917-93899-1jg6jdx/include -I/tmp/llvm20150917-93899-1jg6jdx/projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan/..  -fPIC -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wall -W -Wno-unused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wmissing-field-initializers -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wcovered-switch-default -Wnon-virtual-dtor -std=c++11 -Wall -std=c++11 -arch i386 -arch x86_64   -UNDEBUG   -fPIC -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wall -W -Wno-unused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wmissing-field-initializers -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wcovered-switch-default -Wnon-virtual-dtor -std=c++11 -Wall -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.1.sdk -fPIC -fno-builtin -fno-exceptions -fomit-frame-pointer -funwind-tables -fno-stack-protector -fvisibility=hidden -fno-function-sections -fno-lto -O3 -gline-tables-only -Wno-gnu -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-c99-extensions -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -fno-rtti -ftls-model=initial-exec -o CMakeFiles/RTAsan_dynamic.iossim.dir/asan_posix.cc.o -c /tmp/llvm20150917-93899-1jg6jdx/projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan/asan_posix.cc
rp% cd /tmp/llvm20150917-93899-y384cu/projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan && /usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/clang++   -DASAN_DYNAMIC=1 -DASAN_HAS_EXCEPTIONS=1 -D_DEBUG -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -I/tmp/llvm20150917-93899-y384cu/projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan -I/tmp/llvm20150917-93899-1jg6jdx/projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan -I/tmp/llvm20150917-93899-y384cu/include -I/tmp/llvm20150917-93899-1jg6jdx/include -I/tmp/llvm20150917-93899-1jg6jdx/projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan/..  -fPIC -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wall -W -Wno-unused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wmissing-field-initializers -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wcovered-switch-default -Wnon-virtual-dtor -std=c++11 -Wall -std=c++11 -arch i386 -arch x86_64   -UNDEBUG   -fPIC -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wall -W -Wno-unused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wmissing-field-initializers -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wcovered-switch-default -Wnon-virtual-dtor -std=c++11 -Wall -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -fPIC -fno-builtin -fno-exceptions -fomit-frame-pointer -funwind-tables -fno-stack-protector -fvisibility=hidden -fno-function-sections -fno-lto -O3 -gline-tables-only -Wno-gnu -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-c99-extensions -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -fno-rtti -ftls-model=initial-exec -o CMakeFiles/RTAsan_dynamic.osx.dir/asan_posix.cc.o -c /tmp/llvm20150917-93899-1jg6jdx/projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan/asan_posix.cc


rp% file CMakeFiles/RTAsan_dynamic.iossim.dir/asan_posix.cc.o
CMakeFiles/RTAsan_dynamic.iossim.dir/asan_posix.cc.o: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
CMakeFiles/RTAsan_dynamic.iossim.dir/asan_posix.cc.o (for architecture i386):   Mach-O object i386
CMakeFiles/RTAsan_dynamic.iossim.dir/asan_posix.cc.o (for architecture x86_64): Mach-O 64-bit object x86_64
rp% file CMakeFiles/RTAsan_dynamic.osx.dir/asan_posix.cc.o
CMakeFiles/RTAsan_dynamic.osx.dir/asan_posix.cc.o: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
CMakeFiles/RTAsan_dynamic.osx.dir/asan_posix.cc.o (for architecture i386):  Mach-O object i386
CMakeFiles/RTAsan_dynamic.osx.dir/asan_posix.cc.o (for architecture x86_64):    Mach-O 64-bit object x86_64
```

The searching I did didn't really help; I didn't write the makefile myself (cmake generated), and at least to my eyes there wasn't reason for `make` to print something that it wasn't executing.

Anyone have any idea what is going on?

---

Reproduction steps:

- install homebrew if it isn't already installed
- replace homebrew's llvm formula with the WIP one [here](https://gist.github.com/aw1621107/dccde531d91349d3eaee)
- Run `brew install llvm --with-clang --with-lldb --verbose --debug`
- wait for the build to fail and ask you what to do
- Drop into a debug shell
- cd to `projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan`
- run `make clean`
- run `make asan_posix.o` (or any of the other `*.o` files listed in `make help`
- run `file` on the output file (in `CMakeFiles/RTAsan_dynamic.(osx|iossim).dir/asan_posix.cc.o` for me)
- Repeat the above 3 steps, but copy-pasting the command instead of running `make`

---

Edit: Link to my [environment](https://gist.github.com/aw1621107/3e0b5a36d028f648d7a0) in the shell and during the make process.

Comment: Likely your `/usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/clang++` is accessing some environmental variables which are overwritten via the make process.   You can run `env > shell.log` in the shell and then again (with `> make.log`) in the make recipe, right before the build, and see what differs between the two.

Comment: @John Hmmm, didn't know that was possible. Gave it a try and added a link to a gist containing the environment in the shell and immediately before the build is called. Also got the environment immediately after the build, but it was the same as before the build.

Comment: Nothing looks particularly out of place to me, but it's very possible I'm just missing/not recognizing the important ones... And would environment variables override command line flags?

Comment: How  did you get actual commands being run? AFAIR, you only need `make VERBOSE=1 target` to see what CMake actually calls.

Comment: @arrowd Cmake was invoked with its verbose option enabled, so as far as I could tell the makefiles were already in verbose mode

Comment: I don't see `-arch i386 -arch x86_64   -UNDEBUG` flags in your line, while CMake one have it.

Comment: @arrowd I'm pretty sure they are there... Ctrl/command-F?

Comment: Hum, right. Dunno then, sorry.

Comment: Your `PATH` and `PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR` are different, and would be suspect.   Is `/usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/clang++` an executable, a link or a shell script?  Either way, you may want to do `/usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/clang++ --version` from the makefile and the command line to see if those line up.   You may also want to try setting your ENV in the shell to match exactly that of the Make to see if that makes it more consistent.

Comment: @John That particular [`clang++`](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/ENV/4.3/clang%2B%2B) is a symlink to a different [ruby script](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/ENV/4.3/cc) that does the heavy lifting.

Comment: And you were right! It *is* something in the make environment messing things up.

Comment: And found which one! It's HOMEBREW_CCCFG, set to Osag. No idea why, but I'll be asking the maintainers for sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this question ended up being the same as the linked question. homebrew was changing compiler flags, so the commands that were printed weren't the ones being executed. The fix in the other question also happened to fix this.